# What type of Textures are these?

Tags: modeling, texturing

So I recently downloaded a bunch of models from Animal Crossing New Horizons and I came across these textures that I've honestly no clue what to do with. The file name is "Crv" which I'm going to guess is short for "Curve" but I'm honestly not sure.

If anyone knows how to set these up in the Node Editor, please let me know.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those look like cavity maps (aka CReVice maps)! They're basically a type of ambient occlusion map, meaning a lot of tutorials that apply to ambient occlusion in the node editor will also apply to these.

According to the Polycount wiki:

> A cavity map is a texture that stores small-scale ambient occlusion. Also called a Crevice map. Cavity map is different from Curvature map which stores the convexity/concavity of a mesh.

(Source: http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Cavity_map)

Here's a guide on different texture map types if you're interested! It may help with identifying other textures. https://cgtricks.com/basic-guide-for-testures-map-types-yanko-stefanov